# What is the nonlinearity of felt on a piano's hammer?

Tags: acoustics, material-science

Not a physicist.

I was reading a paper about the piano.

For those unaware of its mechanism, each time a key is pressed, a hammer hits the strings (I will not enter into the details).

Point is, the hammer is covered with felt and there is apparently something nonlinear in that the faster the hammer meets the string, the harder the felt acts on the string.

The end result, acoustically speaking is the well known effect that a louder note will be also richer in high frequencies.

So what happens with the felt that it does not act like a »normal» material?

Article is there, and part of an interesting 5 part lecture on the acoustics of the piano:

http://www.speech.kth.se/music/5_lectures/askenflt/nonlinea.html

Edit: apparently I was not clear enough. I want to know what physically happens with the felt so that it becomes stiffer. I already know it does and I am not looking for formulas either, let alone a lecture about what the word nonlinear means. I want to know what is going on in plain English terms. Then, formulas may be added but not until a proper description of the mechanisms involved is given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Felt consists of very thin hair fibers which have been mechanically tangled into a compressed, semisolid mass by a process known as *felting* (oddly enough). In *soft felt*, the fibers have not been strongly compressed while being tangled up and so the resulting felt is flexible and has low density. Men's fedora hats are made of soft felt. In *hard felt*, the fiber mass has been compressed together really hard while being tangled and its density is greater, and the resulting product is much stiffer. Men's derby ("bowler") hats and old-fashioned cowboy hats are made of harder felt, which retains its shape better.

How a chunk of felt behaves when it is struck against something depends on how open the felted network is i.e., how much air there is inside the network of tangled hair. It is that open space which collapses upon striking, right up to the point where the fibers come into firm contact with one another as the felt mass is being compressed.

When soft felt is squished together with that much force, it suddenly begins resisting further compression because all the open space has been squeezed out of it and it stiffens up in response. The harder the felt is to start with, the quicker it fights back against further compression in this way. This is the cause of the nonlinearity of the compression response of felt.

If a piano hammer faced with moderately hard felt is gently struck against a piano string, its tip compresses slowly and the striking force is distributed out in time and along the length of the string which 1) excites fewer high-frequency overtones and 2) damps off those that it does excite. When it hits the string hard, it compresses enough to "go hard" and more high frequency modes get excited- and fewer of them get damped out during the shorter time the hammer is in contact with the string.

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that a force given by $F$ is applied to the felt of a piano hammer, when it strikes the piano string, so the felt is compressed by a distance $x$. This force depends on $x$.

If this felt behaved like a *linear spring* then the relationship between  $F$ and  $x$ would be a *linear relationship* given by Hooke’s law  $$\tag 1 F = k x$$ where $k$ is called the spring constant and depends on the material in the spring (felt).

But in practice, when an increased force is applied to the  felt pad, the compression will not follow the linear relationship described by  equation (1).  In reality, the felt is designed so that it becomes stiffer the more it gets compressed. In other words, a larger force needs to be applied to produce the same  increase in the  amount of compression.

> So what happens with the felt that it does not act like a »normal» material?

The fact that its stiffness increases when it’s compressed and the fact that the relationship between the applied force and the compression is nonlinear, and does not follow Hooke’s law as explained above.

In such cases, the felt used in piano hammers acts as a *nonlinear spring* that hardens with compression. This is what is meant by “non linear“ in your question above. In fact, the relationship in such cases takes the form $$F = kx^p$$ where $p \gt 1$ is a real number and is called the *effective nonlinearity exponent*.

Comment: It is not clear from your answer why this would produce more hight frequencies/harmonics. In fact, it is quite possible that the presence of more harmonics has nothing to do with the non-linearity of the hammer - a greater force simply makes this harmonics to have energies above the hearing threshold. The appearance of the harmonics themselves have to do with the non-linearity of the string oscillations.

Comment: To this I would add that a soft material takes time to compress and rebound. It pushes on the string relatively slowly. A hard material does not compress. It presses on the string over a shorter time. A long time and low velocity excites the slower moving fundamental mode more and the faster moving high frequencies less.

Comment: @Vadim Yes, that is true but the OP is not asking about that. He/she appears to be asking about what is the origin of this “nonlinear” behaviour/term and its relationship to the felt. Thanks.

Comment: @josephh The question is also about how this non-linear behavior affects the sound. It may be that it is unrelated at all to the sound effect described, although there may be some truth to what mmesser314 said above.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I am looking for. I am looking for details about the physical mechanisms that make felt nonlinear and getting stiffer, i.e. physical events taking place not mere formulas.

Comment: «the felt is designed so that it becomes stiffer the more it gets compressed.» This is what I want details about. How is this achieved?

Comment: @Vadim: no the question is not about how it affects the sound. I know that already. I am asking how the felt  gets stiffer.

Comment: @Exocytosis but one has to explain how *this* effect is produced... and I am not sure that the *filt* and its nonlinearity are the cause.

Comment: @Exocytosis I will add to my answer sometime today if time permits.